# The coordinate page of the graph is displayed but the data is not displayed as a graph in hichart in laravel

Tags: laravel, highcharts, laravel-blade

I want to display data in graphs. The coordinate page of the graph is displayed but the data is not displayed as a graph.
my controller code:

```
public function index(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $chart1 = \Chart::title([
                    'text' => 'Riches of '. $user->name,
                ])->chart([
                    'type'     => 'line', 
                    'renderTo' => 'chart1',
                ])
                ->xaxis([
                    'categories' => [
                        2017,2018,2019,2020
                    ],
                    'labels'     => [
                        'align'     => 'top',
                    ],
                ])
                ->yaxis([
                    'text' => 'This Y Axis',
                ])
                ->legend([
                    'layout'        => 'vertikal',
                    'align'         => 'right',
                    'verticalAlign' => 'middle',
                ])
                ->series([
                        [
                            'name'  => 'Riches',
                            'data'  => [23000,59000, 69000, 87000],
                            'color' => '#0c2959',
                        ]
                    ]
                )
                ->display();

        return  view('user',compact('chart1'));
}
```

my blade file:

```
<div id="chart1"></div>
 {!! $chart1 !!}
```

The output is displayed as follows!
[image]

Comment: Hi @Negar Javadzadeh, Could you provide me with a generated JS code? You probably will be able to use this code: `JSON.stringify(Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions);` in a browser console.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. The result of executing the code you said was something like this  "{"title":{"text":"Riches of Elnaz"},"xAxis":{"categories":[],"labels":{"rotation":15,"align":"top"}},"legend":{"layout":"vertikal","align":"right","verticalAlign":"middle"},"series":[{"name":"Riches","data":[],"color":"#0c2959"}],"chart":{"type":"line","renderTo":"chart"}}". When I comment on this line of my code"<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>" , it shows me the graph.

Comment: "{"title":{"text":"Riches of Elnaz"},"xAxis":{"categories":["1399/5/10","1399/5/10","1399/5/10","1399/5/12","1399/5/13","1399/5/13","1399/5/13","1399/5/13","1399/5/14"],"labels":{"rotation":15,"align":"top"}},"legend":{"layout":"vertikal","align":"right","verticalAlign":"middle"},"series":[{"name":"Riches","data":[100,600,400,69000,3462,3004,8000,34000,3000],"color":"#0c2959"}],"chart":{"type":"line","renderTo":"chart"}}" after the comment, this is the result.

Comment: The options are correct - please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5vqafd8t/ Probably something is wrong in another part of your project.

Comment: yes the problem is <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>.  No JavaScript links work after this line. How can I add chart scripts to this file(app.js)?

Comment: I don't know your project, so it is very hard for me to help you. Only one thing that comes to my mind is that you can try disable animation in your chart, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6pwx9yvj/